# Через раз запускается симулятор iWatch на эмуляции Maverics на VMWare

Tags: ios, vmware

Добрый день.
Очень плохо работает симулятор iWatch на iOS SDK 8.2, добавление в код конструкции вроде инициализации пустого массива приводит к его зависанию. Причем, чтобы получить воможность снова запускать программу, приходится стирать не только строки иницализации, а удалять элементы управления из storyboard. 
Неужели у всех, кто пользуется VMWare такой опыт программирования iWatch? Или SDK настолько сырой, что с этим сталкиваются все?
Я знаю, что пользоватся эмуляторами нехорошо, но я куплю mac как можно скорее.

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом возникает вопрос: а что у вас установлено в VMWare? Чистый OS X или модифицированный каким-то образом типа Hackintosh?

Если стоит модернизированный горе-рукодельщиками, то стоит для начала поставить чистый, если VMWare не умеет подобного, то поставьте в qemu/kvm, в нем чистый 10.9 точно ставится и работает.